# It shows ajax requested blank page when after signed in with Devise authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

When the user is not signed in, it shows `"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing"` when after he's tried to execute the actions which need authentication.

That's just how I want it so it's okay.

However, the problem is that, it takes user to the blank page(which is ajax requested url so it's blank) when after he signed in.

Is it possible to let him stay at the same previous page, and just let it execute ajax request with `remote=>true`?

How can I handle this kind of problem?

[UPDATE]

**users_controller.rb**

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:follow, :unfollow]

def follow
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
    current_user.follow(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js {render :action=>"follow.js"}
    end
end
```

**view**

```
  <% if current_user.following?(user) %>
    <%= link_to(unfollow_user_path(user), :remote => true) do %>
     Following
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to(follow_user_path(user) ,:remote => true) do %>
     Follow
    <%end%>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: It is a bit difficult to understand your problem. In your app, there is an ajax operation. If the user invokes it before logging in, he is taken to a blank page? Is this your problem? Can you paste the controller action and the html link which is creating this problem..

Comment: @manoj Sorry about my poor explanation. if the user invokes ajax operation before sign in, it takes him to `sign in` page. Then he probably will type his email and password, and sign in. But it shows blank page right after signed in. I will paste my code. Hold on just a bit please.

Comment: @manoj Sorry for late reply. I updated my question:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when the user is not logged in and executes a request he is forced to sign in, when he successfully sign in he is redirected to previous page, i.e. redirect_to :back, but when he executes an ajax request, there is no html page that renders ajax action(def follow).

```
def follow
   @user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
   current_user.follow(@user)
   if request.xhr?  # ajax request
     respond_to do |format|
       format.js {render :action=>"follow.js"}
     end
   else
       redirect_to home_path # or any other path
   end
end
```